# Timeout on spreadsheet api

Tags: python, timeout, google-sheets-api

Do you know why I have this error ?

> timeout: The read operation timed out

How to except it please ? From which package can I retrieve the tiemout exception ?

> File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\bot\sheetapi.py", line 58, in
>   update
>       spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME, valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient_helpers.py",
>   line 134, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 892, in execute
>       headers=self.headers,
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 195, in _retry_request
>       raise exception
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py",
>   line 172, in _retry_request
>       resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py",
>   line 198, in request
>       uri, method, body=body, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1514, in request
>       (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1264, in _request
>       (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1217, in _conn_request
>       response = conn.getresponse()
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in
>   getresponse
>       response.begin()
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in
>   begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in
>   _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
>       return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
>       return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
>
> File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
>       v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
>
> timeout: The read operation timed out